# Correct type declaration for method returning iterator to C array

Tags: c++, arrays, types, iterator, declaration

I can iterate through a C-style array this way:

```
char foo[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

for (auto it = std::begin(foo); it != std::end(foo); ++it)
{
    *it = 'k'; //values of foo are correctly modified
}
```

Now suppose I want to wrap the array inside a class, and expose a `begin()` and `end()` methods that return the relative iterators.
I tried the following:

```
template<size_t size>
class StackMemPolicy
{
private:
    char mem[size];

public:
    typedef typename  std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char> iter;
    iter  begin() 
    {
        return std::begin(mem);
    }
    iter  end()
    {
        return std::end(mem);
    }
 }
```

It seems the returned type declaration is wrong, and the following calling code don't compile:

```
StackMemPolicy<4> bar;
for (auto it = bar.begin(); it != bar.end(); ++it)
{
    *it = 'k';
}
```

The error is the following:

> Error 1   error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a
>   left-hand operand of type 'StackMemPolicy<4>::iter' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)

Can anyone tell me where's my error?

Comment: Any reason not to use `using iter = decltype(std::begin(mem))`?

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: no reason not to use it (I'll refactor this way). I was just curious about the type declaration though. I'm really rusty with C++ and often new c++11 facilities still hide too much details to me.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: btw, as such it seems not compile (not able to deduce type)

Comment: Hm, that's odd, works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba971253946db34e) and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5b4d7f410c8e2dc). Maybe post a question with SSCCE? (I am not all to familiar with `decltype` either, maybe my suggestion was dumb/falls (although I don't think so tbh :) ))

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: I see you're using clang. I'm using MSVC maybe it's related. Btw I'll post a new question with an SSCCE. It does worth to be known.

Comment: @Heisenbug Visual C++ 2012 fails with `could not deduce template argument for '_Ty (&)[_Size]' from 'unknown'`. 2015 RC compiles it correctly. I couldn't find a workaround, since it doesn't seem to lookup `mem` correctly.

Comment: thanks for confirming that's a VS2012 issue. I won't post another question then. VS2013 community seems to have the same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::iterator` is meant to be used as a base class. From 24.4.2/1:

```
namespace std {
  template<class Category, class T, class Distance = ptrdiff_t,
    class Pointer = T*, class Reference = T&>
  struct iterator {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Distance difference_type;
    typedef Pointer pointer;
    typedef Reference reference;
    typedef Category iterator_category;
  };
}
```

It only gives you [some typedefs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) and won't magically implement all the required operators. In your case, `begin()` and `end()` should probably just return `char*`, which [already has specializations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits#Specializations) for `std::iterator_traits`.

However, if your iterator has to be smarter (maybe this is some sort of circular buffer, for example), you would have to create your own iterator class and implement the required operators. For that iterator to work with various features in the standard library (such as `std::iterator_traits`), you'll need predefined typedefs such as `value_type`, `iterator_category`, etc.

Since getting those right can sometimes be tricky, `std::iterator` will define those for you based on the given template parameters. Here's an example of [using `std::iterator_traits` with an iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags#Example).

Note that as of C++17, `std::iterator` has been deprecated for [various reasons](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html#2.1). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031805/preparation-for-stditerator-being-deprecated) has some workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

[It works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e054d0b8f6e2adce) if I change:

```
typedef typename  std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char> iter;
```

to:

```
typedef char * iter;
```

Comment: Although this is valid for the array type here, it's poor advice for the general case, where another container type is used.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you don't want to modify the behavior, you should just return `std::begin(mem)` which is nothing more than a `char *`.

See [see 2'nd overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)

Answer (score 2):

Using trailing return type syntax of function you can achieve it as follows:

```
template<size_t size>
class StackMemPolicy
{
private:
    char mem[size];

public:
    //typedef typename  std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char> iter;
     auto begin() -> decltype(std::begin(mem))
    {
        return std::begin(mem);
    }
     auto  end() -> decltype(std::end(mem))
    {
        return std::end(mem);
    }
 };

 int main()
 { 
    StackMemPolicy<3> bar;

    for (auto it = bar.begin(); it != bar.end(); ++it)
   {
     *it = 'k';
   }


    for (auto it = bar.begin(); it != bar.end(); ++it)
   {
     std::cout<<*it;
   }

 }
```